# Death penalty for non-Jews

Tags: halacha, gentiles, capital-punishment, criminal-procedure

Murder in the Torah is punished by the death penalty, but with many conditions.

Were the rules of death penalty the same for Jews and non-Jews living in the holy land?
What were the differences?

Was the Sanhedrin able to judge non Jews?

Comment: probably since it never even came close to happening, so it was such a theoretical, that rabbis never came up with lots of conditions

Answer (score -3):

There are two laws in the 7 noahide laws which pertain to this. The first being not to mirder and the second to establish courts of justice. The court systems would set up procedures of how to deal with witnesses and how the offender should be punished.